# Having problems with the contents of my ArrayList printing multiple times

Tags: java, arraylist

This is my first time posting here, and I'm still very new at programming (just started Java not too long ago), so any advice you guys could give me about how to fix my problem would be well appreciated! I hope I follow the guidelines here on my first post!

In the grand scheme of this project, I'm trying to sort my array of "Teams" to determine who had the most "laps, riders, and donations" related to a marathon. The Team class consists of Rider objects.

This is the loop that I'm using to iterate through my Team array with the methods that exist in the Team class.

```
ArrayList<Team> team = new ArrayList<Team>();

for(int i=0; i<team.size(); i++){
        team.get(i).mostDonations(team);
        team.get(i).mostLaps(team);
        team.get(i).mostRiders(team);
    }
```

This is my Team class. It's filled with the required constructors, setters, and getters, as well as methods that calculate totals. But below should be the relevant lines of code, I think. (Let me know if I'm leaving anything out!)

```
public class Team {
private String teamName;
private String teamAbbreviation;
private ArrayList<Riders> riders = new ArrayList<Riders>();
DecimalFormat decimal = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");

public double totalDonations(){
    double totalDonations = 0;
    for(int i=0; i < riders.size(); i++){
        totalDonations += riders.get(i).getAmount();
    }
    return totalDonations;
}

public int totalLaps(){
    int totalLaps = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < riders.size(); i++){
        totalLaps += riders.get(i).getLaps();
    }
    return totalLaps;
}

public int totalRiders(){
    int totalRiders = 0;
    for (int i =0; i < riders.size(); i++){
        totalRiders += riders.size();
    }
    return totalRiders;
}

public void mostLaps(ArrayList<Team> Teams){
    int max = 0;
    int indexOfMax = 0;
    for(int i=0; i < Teams.size(); i++){
        if(Teams.get(i).totalDonations() > max){
            max = Teams.get(i).totalLaps();
            indexOfMax = i;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The team with the most laps is: " + Teams.get(indexOfMax).getName() + "!");
}

public void mostRiders(ArrayList<Team> Teams){
    int max = 0;
    int indexOfMax = 0;
    for(int i=0; i < Teams.size(); i++){
        if(Teams.get(i).totalRiders() > max){
            max = Teams.get(i).totalRiders();
            indexOfMax = i;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The team with the most riders is: " + Teams.get(indexOfMax).getName() + "!");
}

public void mostDonations(ArrayList<Team> Teams){
    double max = 0.0;
    int indexOfMax = 0;
    for(int i=0; i < Teams.size(); i++){
        if(Teams.get(i).totalDonations() > max){
            max = Teams.get(i).totalDonations();
            indexOfMax = i;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The team with the most donations is: " + Teams.get(indexOfMax).getName() + "!");
}
```

And this is my Rider class.

```
public class Riders {

private String name;
private String hometown;
private String id;
private int laps;
private double amountRaised;

public Riders(){
    name = "";
    hometown = "";
    id = "";
    laps = 0;
    amountRaised = 0.0;
}

public Riders(String Name, String Hometown, String ID, int Laps){
    name = Name;
    hometown = Hometown;
    id = ID;
    laps = Laps;
    amountRaised = 0.0;
}

public void setName(String Name){
    name = Name;
}

public void setHometown(String Hometown){
    hometown = Hometown;
}

public void setAbbreviation(String ID){
    id = ID;
}

public void setLaps(int Laps){
    laps = Laps;
}

public void setAmount(double Amount){
    amountRaised = Amount;
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}

public String getHometown(){
    return hometown;
}

public String getID(){
    return id;
}

public int getLaps(){
    return laps;
}

public double getAmount(){
    return amountRaised;
}
public String toString(){
    String s = "Rider Name: " + name + "\nHometown: " + hometown + "\nID: " + id + "\nLaps: " + laps;
    return s;
}

}
```

The output, however, looks like this:

> The team with the most donations is: Zebra Army Members!
>
> The team with the most laps is: Xtremely Together!
>
> The team with the most riders is: Zebra Army Members!
>
> The team with the most donations is: Zebra Army Members!
>
> The team with the most laps is: Xtremely Together!
>
> The team with the most riders is: Zebra Army Members!
>
> The team with the most donations is: Zebra Army Members!
>
> The team with the most laps is: Xtremely Together!
>
> The team with the most riders is: Zebra Army Members!
>
> The team with the most donations is: Zebra Army Members!
>
> The team with the most laps is: Xtremely Together!
>
> The team with the most riders is: Zebra Army Members!
>
> The team with the most donations is: Zebra Army Members!
>
> The team with the most laps is: Xtremely Together!
>
> The team with the most riders is: Zebra Army Members!
>
> The team with the most donations is: Zebra Army Members!
>
> The team with the most laps is: Xtremely Together!
>
> The team with the most riders is: Zebra Army Members!
>
> The team with the most donations is: Zebra Army Members!
>
> The team with the most laps is: Xtremely Together!
>
> The team with the most riders is: Zebra Army Members!
>
> The team with the most donations is: Zebra Army Members!
>
> The team with the most laps is: Xtremely Together!
>
> The team with the most riders is: Zebra Army Members!
>
> The team with the most donations is: Zebra Army Members!
>
> The team with the most laps is: Xtremely Together!
>
> The team with the most riders is: Zebra Army Members!
>
> The team with the most donations is: Zebra Army Members!
>
> The team with the most laps is: Xtremely Together!
>
> The team with the most riders is: Zebra Army Members!

I'm very confused as to why it's printing the same three lines over and over again. I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Your Team class logic is wrong. You should not be trying to find which team did the most laps inside that class. You should instead calculate how many laps total a team has done. Then maybe create another class or method to determine which team did the most laps.

Comment: So you class should have variables for total donations, total laps, and numberOfRiders.

Comment: The Team class has methods for total donations, total laps, and total riders as well. I've added them to the original post.

Comment: in you loop you call `mostDonations(team);` over and over again, with exactly the same input (`team`) so why do you expect the output to change ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below loop iterates over your `ArrayList<Team>` and prints three lines per `Team` item.

```
for(int i=0; i<team.size(); i++){
    team.get(i).mostDonations(team);
    team.get(i).mostLaps(team);
    team.get(i).mostRiders(team);
}
```

---

Now, you are also passing the `team` through the above loop.

```
for(int i=0; i < Teams.size(); i++){
    if(Teams.get(i).totalDonations() > max){
        max = Teams.get(i).totalDonations(); // always goes for the max team object
        indexOfMax = i;
    }
}
```

---

Update: A quick way is to remove the for loop calling the three methods.

```
if(team != null) {
    team.get(0).mostDonations(team);
    team.get(0).mostLaps(team);
    team.get(0).mostRiders(team);
}
```

I will verify how efficient this is for your code.

Comment: Ahh, I think I understand. So I'm doubling it by passing it while also iterating it through my for loop in the main class? I guess I was under the impression that I had to pass it as well in order for it to work. Any tips on how I can fix it?

Comment: Hey, I have updated my answer. Kindly let me know if it helps, else I will modify

Comment: Okay, I'll try it! One more question: does it matter that the index is zero for all three calls? Would it change the output if I used a different number for get()? Or is it all determined by the fact that team is being passed?

Comment: So, it won't really matter in your case as you are passing the `team` ArrrayList object to the respective methods who iterate the list again

Answer (score 0):

The more you learn about programming, the more important design becomes. I still think your class is of a terrible design. I have create a little app to demonstrate a slightly better design.

> Team Class:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package javaapplication16;

import java.util.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Sedrick
 */
public class Team {

    private String teamName;
    private List<String> playerName;
    private List<Integer> age;
    private int numOfMembers;
    private double membersAverageAge;

    public Team(String teamName, List<String> playerName, List<Integer> age)
    {
        this.teamName = teamName;
        this.playerName = playerName;
        this.age = age;
        this.numOfMembers = playerName.size();
        this.membersAverageAge = caculateAvgAge(this.age);
    }

    private static double caculateAvgAge(List<Integer> age)
    {
        int sum = 0;

        if (age.size() > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < age.size(); i++) {
                sum += age.get(i);
            }
        }
        else {
            return Double.NaN;
        }

        return (double) sum / (double) age.size();
    }

    /**
     * @return the teamName
     */
    public String getTeamName()
    {
        return teamName;
    }

    /**
     * @param teamName the teamName to set
     */
    public void setTeamName(String teamName)
    {
        this.teamName = teamName;
    }

    /**
     * @return the playerName
     */
    public List<String> getPlayerName()
    {
        return playerName;
    }

    /**
     * @param playerName the playerName to set
     */
    public void setPlayerName(List<String> playerName)
    {
        this.playerName = playerName;
    }

    /**
     * @return the age
     */
    public List<Integer> getAge()
    {
        return age;
    }

    /**
     * @param age the age to set
     */
    public void setAge(List<Integer> age)
    {
        this.age = age;
    }

    /**
     * @return the numOfMembers
     */
    public int getNumOfMembers()
    {
        return numOfMembers;
    }

    /**
     * @param numOfMembers the numOfMembers to set
     */
    public void setNumOfMembers(int numOfMembers)
    {
        this.numOfMembers = numOfMembers;
    }

    /**
     * @return the membersAverageAge
     */
    public double getMembersAverageAge()
    {
        return membersAverageAge;
    }

    /**
     * @param membersAverageAge the membersAverageAge to set
     */
    public void setMembersAverageAge(double membersAverageAge)
    {
        this.membersAverageAge = membersAverageAge;
    }

}
```

> Main Class:

```
import java.util.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Sedrick
 */
public class JavaApplication16 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // TODO code application logic here
        List<String> cowPlayer = new ArrayList();
        List<Integer> cowPlayerAge = new ArrayList();
        cowPlayer.add("Tim");
        cowPlayerAge.add(20);
        cowPlayer.add("Jane");
        cowPlayerAge.add(23);
        cowPlayer.add("Kim");
        cowPlayerAge.add(25);
        cowPlayer.add("Chris");
        cowPlayerAge.add(10);

        Team cow = new Team("Cows", cowPlayer, cowPlayerAge);

        List<String> frogPlayer = new ArrayList();
        List<Integer> frogPlayerAge = new ArrayList();
        frogPlayer.add("Dana");
        frogPlayerAge.add(21);
        frogPlayer.add("Jack");
        frogPlayerAge.add(19);
        frogPlayer.add("Jill");
        frogPlayerAge.add(30);

        Team frog = new Team("Frogs", frogPlayer, frogPlayerAge);

        System.out.println(cow.getTeamName() + " info");
        System.out.println("\tNumber of members: " + cow.getNumOfMembers());
        System.out.println("\tNumber of members: " + cow.getMembersAverageAge());
        System.out.println("\tPlayers Name and Age");
        for (int i = 0; i < cow.getPlayerName().size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("\t\t" + cow.getPlayerName().get(i) + " - " + cow.getAge().get(i));
        }

        System.out.println(frog.getTeamName() + " info");
        System.out.println("\tNumber of members: " + frog.getNumOfMembers());
        System.out.println("\tNumber of members: " + frog.getMembersAverageAge());
        System.out.println("\tPlayers Name and Age");
        for (int i = 0; i < frog.getPlayerName().size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("\t\t" + frog.getPlayerName().get(i) + " - " + frog.getAge().get(i));
        }

        List<Team> teams = new ArrayList();
        teams.add(cow);
        teams.add(frog);

        System.out.println("Team with the most players: " + whichTeamHasTheMostPlayers(teams));
        System.out.println("Team whose players average age is higher: " + whichTeamHasTheHighestAverageAge(teams));

    }

    //If there are more than one team with the same number of players this will not work correctly.
    static private String whichTeamHasTheMostPlayers(List<Team> teams)
    {

        int mostPlayersIndex = 0;//assume the first team has the most players;
        int amountOfPlayers = teams.get(0).getNumOfMembers();
        for (int i = 1; i < teams.size(); i++) {
            if (teams.get(i).getNumOfMembers() > amountOfPlayers) {
                mostPlayersIndex = i;
                amountOfPlayers = teams.get(i).getNumOfMembers();
            }
        }

        return teams.get(mostPlayersIndex).getTeamName();
    }

    //If there are more than one team with the same average this will not work correctly.
    static private String whichTeamHasTheHighestAverageAge(List<Team> teams)
    {
        int highestAvgIndex = 0;//assume the first team has the most players;
        double teamAvg = teams.get(0).getMembersAverageAge();
        for (int i = 1; i < teams.size(); i++) {
            if (teams.get(i).getMembersAverageAge() > highestAvgIndex) {
                highestAvgIndex = i;
                teamAvg = teams.get(i).getMembersAverageAge();
            }
        }

        return teams.get(highestAvgIndex).getTeamName();
    }

}
```

Comment: This app assumes that all or your List are >= 1 in size.